# PHP !== operator

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and unfamiliar with the `!==` and `===` operators. Are Logic #1 and #2 below equivalent? And if not, why so? Basically, the code reads values from a csv row in a file, and if the value is empty it disregards empty or null values

```
//Logic #1
$value = readValue();
//skip empty values
if ( !$value || $value === '') {
   print "empty value found";
}else{
    doSomething();
}

//Logic #2
$value = readValue();
if ( $value && $value !== '' ) {
   doSomething();
}else{ //skip empty values
   print "empty value found";
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could try it with different values and types, just make a small script, loop through, find out.

Comment: The second check in both `if`s is superfluous, as already implied by the first part of the condition. `!'' === true`.

Comment: I'm reading text from a file and the type comparison confuses me as to what I can do to test it, since it's just strings.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the `==` and `===` operators, those should be identical.

- `==` is the opposite of `!=`
- `===` is the opposite of `!==`

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/6352706) for more information on the difference between `==` and `===`.

---

To improve your code a bit, I would suggest using the `empty()` function which will check for nulls and empty strings.

Something like this:

```
if (empty($value)) echo "nothing to see here";
else doSomething();
```

Comment: fixed it for them.

Comment: *"your question about the `==` and `===` operators"*: The OP never mentioned `==` ... You seem to be answering a different question.